# How to move an image into a folder using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, upload

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#user_img").change(function(){
            var file_data = $('#user_img').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            alert(form_data);                             
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
                }
             });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="file" name="user_img" id="user_img" />
```

upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) 
{
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else 
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/user/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo "successfull";
}
?>
```

In this code I have a simple input field through which I want to move an image inside a folder without submit button. Now, What happen when I upload any image it show me `[object FormData]` and then `successfull` but image are not move into that folder. I have don't know why? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You should be checking the  status of `move_uploaded_file`. Perhaps the directory you are using doesn't exist (have you tried `realpath` on it?) or you don't have permission to write to it.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` and check what it contains. Since you're working with relative paths, check that the path to the uploaded file is correct: `var_dump(realpath('images/user));`. If it is correct, check if the folder is writable: `var_dump(is_writable('images/user'));`

Comment: You can also check your servers error log to see if you get any errors, or add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after you turn on error reporting.

Comment: I have check  via `var_dump(realpath('images/user));` it shows `bool(false)` what does it mean @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Thank You @MagnusEriksson. I got my error.

Comment: As the manual says, _"realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist."_.

Comment: Yes, you are right it a path problem. Thank you once again @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I would recommend using absolute paths. One way is to use `$path = __DIR__ . '/path/relative/from/the/current/file';`.

Comment: inside your upload script check also if the temporary file was uploaded. You can use the `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` function. also for the destination upload path, add a variable to store it like this `$p = 'images/user'.$_FILES['file']['name']`, then pass it to the `move_uploaded_file()` function